# Data is being inserted multiple times in table using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I am using this AJAX for inserting data in table but problem is data is inserting multiple times.Actually I have created one form with login,if login is correct then data will insert into database.Problem is if we give wrong username or pass multiple time then data is also inserted multiple times.ex if we enter username pass 3 times wrong then data is inserted 3 times after we give correct login.I am new in AJAX.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{


$("#simple-post").click(function()
{
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
    {
        $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var postData ="";
        postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        alert(postData);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {

            window.location = "Dealer/PostPropertyAdvanceDetails.php?sdfdsf=sf";


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });

    $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});

});
</script>
```

Here's my php code (I think there is no problem with php) :

```
<?php
ob_start();

session_start(); 

include 'CUserDB.php';





include 'config.php';



$myusername=$_POST['txtusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['txtpassword']; 
//$typ= $_POST['type'];


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
//$typ = stripslashes($typ);    
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);


$qry = "SELECT UserName,Type_user FROM login WHERE UserName = '".$myusername."' AND password = '".$mypassword."' ";





$result = mysql_query($qry) or die ("Query failed");

$UserData = mysql_fetch_array($result);




    if($UserData['UserName'] != '')

        {
            session_start(); 

             $_SESSION['UserId'] = $myusername;

        $typ = $UserData['Type_user'];



    if   ( $typ == "Dealer" || $typ == "Individual" || $typ == "Builder")
    { 




         //save details

$PostPropertyFor=$_POST['rdoSalesAndRent'];



$PropertyType=$_POST['propertyType'];
$TransactionType = "";
if (isset($_POST['rdoNewPropResale']))
 {

     $TransactionType =$_POST['rdoNewPropResale'];
 }

$City=$_POST['cmbCity'];
$Location=$_POST['cmbLocation'];

$NameofProject=$_POST['txtNameOfProject'];

$SelectProject=$_POST['rdoProjAndSociety'];
$BedRoom=$_POST['Bedrooms'];
$BathRoom=$_POST['bathrooms'];
$Furnished=$_POST['furnished'];

if (isset($_POST['txtCoveredArea']))
 {
$CoveredArea=$_POST['txtCoveredArea'];
$CoveredAreaSize=$_POST['coveredAreasize'];
$FinalCoveredArea = $CoveredArea.".".$CoveredAreaSize;
$FinalCoveredArea = trim($FinalCoveredArea);
 };



if (isset($_POST['txtPlotNland']))
 {
$PlotArea=$_POST['txtPlotNland'];
$PlotAreaSize=$_POST['plotareaSize'];
$FinalPlotArea = $PlotArea.".". $PlotAreaSize;
$FinalPlotArea = trim($FinalPlotArea);
 };


$FinalCarpetArea = "";
if (isset($_POST['txtCarpet']))
 {
$CarpetArea=$_POST['txtCarpet'];
$CarpetAreaSize=$_POST['carpetareaSize'];
$FinalCarpetArea = $CarpetArea.".".$CarpetAreaSize;
$FinalCarpetArea = trim($FinalCarpetArea);
 };

$TotalPrice=$_POST['txtTotalPrice'];

$FinalPerUnitPrice = "";
if (isset($_POST['txtPerUnit']))
 {
  $PerUnitPrice=$_POST['txtPerUnit'];
$PerUnitSize=$_POST['perunitsize'];
$FinalPerUnitPrice = $PerUnitPrice .".". $PerUnitSize;
$FinalPerUnitPrice = trim($FinalPerUnitPrice);
 };

$DisplayPriceToUser ="";
 if (isset($_POST['rdoYesorNo']))
 {

    $DisplayPriceToUser=$_POST['rdoYesorNo']; 
    $DisplayPriceToUser=trim($DisplayPriceToUser);
 }

$FloorNo=$_POST['floorNumber'];
$TotalFloors=$_POST['txtTotalFloors'];
$Description=$_POST['txtCompDesc'];

$PossessionStatus ="";
 if (isset($_POST['rdoUnderConstrucionNready']))
 {
     $PossessionStatus=$_POST['rdoUnderConstrucionNready'];
 }

if(isset($_POST['txtMonthlyRent']))
 {
$MonthlyRent=$_POST['txtMonthlyRent'];
$MonthlyRent=trim($MonthlyRent);
 }

$AvailableFrom = "";
if(isset($_POST['rdoAvailableFor']))
 {
  $AvailableFrom=$_POST['rdoAvailableFor'];
 $AvailableFrom=trim($AvailableFrom);

 }



$PostPropertyFor=trim($PostPropertyFor);
$PropertyType=trim($PropertyType);
$TransactionType =trim($TransactionType);
$City=trim($City);
$Location=trim($Location);
$NameofProject=trim($NameofProject);
$SelectProject=trim($SelectProject);
$BedRoom=trim($BedRoom);
$BathRoom=trim($BathRoom);
$Furnished=trim($Furnished);




$TotalPrice=trim($TotalPrice);



$FloorNo=trim($FloorNo);
$TotalFloors=trim($TotalFloors);
$Description=trim($Description);
$PossessionStatus=trim($PossessionStatus);



$Username = $_SESSION['UserId'];


   $str ="Call sp_SaveDealerPostProperty('".$PostPropertyFor."','".$PropertyType."','".$TransactionType."','".$City."','".$Location."','".$NameofProject."','".$SelectProject."','".$BedRoom."','".$BathRoom."','".$Furnished."','".$FinalCoveredArea."','".$FinalPlotArea."','".$FinalCarpetArea."','".$TotalPrice."','".$FinalPerUnitPrice."','".$DisplayPriceToUser."','".$FloorNo."','".$TotalFloors."','".$Description."','".$PossessionStatus."','".$MonthlyRent."','".$AvailableFrom."','".$Username."')";

           if(!mysql_query($str))
{ 
 die('Error:'.mysql_error()); 
 } 
  else 
 { 

     $query="SELECT MAX(property_Id) as id FROM dealerpostproperty WHERE UserName ='".$Username."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(); 
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$LastId = $row->id; 



             $_SESSION['LastId'] = $LastId;



//make directory for property with property id if not exist

$uploaded_files_location = "propertyImages/".$_SESSION['LastId']."/";
echo $uploaded_files_location;
  if (file_exists($uploaded_files_location))
   {
} 
else 
{
    mkdir($uploaded_files_location);
}

  }






}   
    }

   else 

    { 
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
echo " wrong username or password";
/*          echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Wrong Username or Password!");';
echo 'location.href="index.php"';
echo '</script>';  */

    }

?>
```

Comment: and where is ur PHP code?

Comment: take the `$("#ajaxform").submit` function out of the click as you will be binding a new submit event to the form everytime you click the button - you should just need to bind it once, you probably don't need to bind anything to the click event actually as your submit event should take care of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
    var postData ="";
    postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    alert(postData);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {

        window.location = "Dealer/PostPropertyAdvanceDetails.php?sdfdsf=sf";


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#simple-post").click(function()
{
    $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: What's changed in this answer from the OP?